# Dificuldade em acertar os button no layout

Tags: android, button, layout

Não consigo colocar os buttons no layout como quero. Queria deixar um button ao centro e os outros no fundo (bottom)  por baixo do que estao ao centro. So que nao ficam correctos e nao consigo acertar para quando mudo de resolução ficarem corretos.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="523dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hohoho" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:gravity="top">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Você pode prover um wireframe ou imagem simples do resultado que você espera?

Comment: sim posso, usar uma imagem simples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu layout "maior" tem que ter um weightSum de 2, porque dentro dele tem 2 outros layouts. Esses dois layouts menores devem ser RelativeLayout com o atributo layout_weight de 1 cada layout, para totalizar a soma de valor 2.
Desse modo, a tela ficará dividida ao meio perfeitamente.
Então, dentro do layout de cima voce poe o botão e coloca a gravidade do layout para jogar tudo para baixo. No layout de baixo, voce coloca os botões e coloca a gravidade para cima. 
Desse modo, todos os botões vão ficar perfeitamente centralizados independentemente do tamanho da tela.